# How to connect to wampserver mySQL database from server website?

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

I have a web application hosted on the server and I am unable to connect to the database.Currently I am using the codes:

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","labelimagetool");
```

How do I connect to the database from a web application hosted on the server?

Comment: Those credentials are provided to you by your host admin. Unless provide it yourself.

Comment: @Roshan Im sorry I do not understand.Which credentials re u referring to?

Comment: you move the database to the remote sever. just like you moved the files there. At least i think thats what you are asking

Comment: @AdminTester Credentials from remote database server. Are you using paid hosting?

Comment: @tim but how do i move the database?

Comment: @Roshan Sorry i do not know if we are using paid hosting as it is done by another developer.He pushes my codes to the server.

Comment: @AdminTester you know the server's IP? You can try this `$conn = new mysqli("**SERVER IP HERE**","root","","labelimagetool");` Make sure the username and password and database name is correct to connect successfully.

Comment: @Roshan I tried and it says Connection timed out.

Comment: Maybe the server has no DB server installed?

Comment: @Roshan then how do i install wamp on the server?

Comment: You need to find out more about your environment. As you dont seem to know much about it, how are we going to be able to advise you

Comment: PS: A web site should not be using `root` to connect to the database. Big security risk

Comment: Should we assume that you developed this site using WAMPServer on your local PC and now you are moving the site to a remote server?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes.Using root is just an example.